# AWS QuickSight: ListDashboards API throwing 302 error back

Tags: amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I was trying to list the dashboards available / configured in the AWS QuickSight using the QuickSight APIs. Unfortunately there are very very few examples available on the internet and hence thought to seek some help.

Following is what my java code looks like:

`

```
    @RequestMapping(name = "listDashboards", value = "/quicksight/listdashboards", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ListDashboardsResult> listDashboards() {
        String endPointURI = "https://us-east-1.quicksight.aws.amazon.com";
        EndpointConfiguration endPointConfig = new EndpointConfiguration(endPointURI, "us-east-1");
        AmazonQuickSightClientBuilder awsQsBuilder = AmazonQuickSightClientBuilder.standard()//.withRegion(AWSProperties.getRegion())
        .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                new BasicAWSCredentials("XYZ_ACCESS_KEY", "ABC_SECRET_KEY")));
        awsQsBuilder.setEndpointConfiguration(endPointConfig);
        AmazonQuickSight quickSightClient = awsQsBuilder.build();
        ListDashboardsRequest listDashboards = new ListDashboardsRequest();
        listDashboards.setAwsAccountId("ACCOUNT_ID");
        ListDashboardsResult result = quickSightClient.listDashboards(listDashboards);
        return new ResponseEntity<ListDashboardsResult>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

`

I'm trying to test this from my local machine. I've added the localhost URL https URL to the "Accepted Domains" in the quicksight "Domains and Embedding" section.

[image]

However when I run the application and try to retrieve the list, I always end up seeing the following response being returned from the quicksight.

```
com.amazonaws.services.quicksight.model.AmazonQuickSightException: null (Service: AmazonQuickSight; Status Code: 302; Error Code: null; Request ID: b43aabfb-7852-449c-854d-6d88f1f11c13; Proxy: null)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1862) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1415) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1384) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1154) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:811) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:779) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:753) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:713) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:695) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:559) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:539) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.quicksight.AmazonQuickSightClient.doInvoke(AmazonQuickSightClient.java:9215) ~[aws-java-sdk-quicksight-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.quicksight.AmazonQuickSightClient.invoke(AmazonQuickSightClient.java:9182) ~[aws-java-sdk-quicksight-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.quicksight.AmazonQuickSightClient.invoke(AmazonQuickSightClient.java:9171) ~[aws-java-sdk-quicksight-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.quicksight.AmazonQuickSightClient.executeListDashboards(AmazonQuickSightClient.java:5370) ~[aws-java-sdk-quicksight-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.amazonaws.services.quicksight.AmazonQuickSightClient.listDashboards(AmazonQuickSightClient.java:5339) ~[aws-java-sdk-quicksight-1.12.195.jar:na]
at com.example.demo.quicksight.QuickSightDashboardUtils.listDashboards(QuickSightDashboardUtils.java:62) ~[main/:na]
at com.example.demo.quicksight.QuickSightController.listDashboards(QuickSightController.java:20) ~[main/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1071) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:670) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.24.jar:5.3.24]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.69.jar:9.0.69]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
```

Is there anything else I am missing here?

Comment: The accepted domains url is only for when you're embedding quicksight in an app. Also note that you cannot embed on localhost.

You're getting a 302 which is an http redirect.

Comment: Thanks for helping @JeffPaquette. Looks like, testing this functionality locally is quite a challenge apparently and unfortunately. Had to enable https for all local services involved and had to a couple of changes in quicksight as well. This is something that probably needs some simplification for ease of unit testing. But thanks again for pointing that out.

Comment: There's been a recent change to quick sight that does allow embedding from localhost! its a huge improvement